# Parallelize a function using xargs and separate variables

Tags: shell-script, xargs, function

I have a four line text file with 1, 2, 3 & 4 on each line. Also, I have a function that I want to parallelize: `foo() { echo "$1 is not $2"; }`

I export the function: `export -f foo`

Now I want to call the function with parameters from the text files using `xargs` to parallelize. **AND** I also want to use a variable (`a=0`) as a parameter in the function. So, I would call the function as: `cat txt | xargs -I "{}" -P 2 bash -c 'foo {} $a'`

**BUT** this ignores the variable (`a=0`). And outputs:

> "1 is not"  ... "4 is not" etc

If I call: `cat txt | xargs -I "{}" -P 2 bash -c 'foo {} 0'` it works and I get the correct output

> "1 is not **0**"  ... "4 is not **0**" etc

But I need to call it using the variable (`a=0`) and not using zero. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6):

Embedding the `{}` in the shell code is always a bad idea as it introduces a command injection vulnerability. It's always better to pass data as separate (non-code) arguments.

Also `-I`, without `-d`/`-0` still chokes on quotes and backslashes and strips leading blanks. With GNU `xargs` (which you must be using as you're already using the `-P` GNU extension), best is to use `-d '\n'` to pass each line of input as separate argument

```
xargs -a txt -rd'\n' -P2 -n1 bash -c 'foo "$2" "$1"' bash "$a"
```

(calls one `bash` invocation for each `1` line of the input with the contents of `$a` and the current line as separate arguments which are referred as `$1` and `$2` in the inline shell script).

Or with `-I`:

```
xargs -a txt -rd'\n' -P2 -I'{}' bash -c 'foo "$1" "$2"' bash {} "$a"
```

Here you could switch to `zsh` which has a `zargs` autoloadable function which can do parallel processing à la GNU `xargs`, including of functions without having to run separate shell invocations or exporting functions like `xargs` does.

```
$ autoload zargs
$ foo() print -r - $1 is not $2
$ zargs -P2 -I {} {1..4} -- foo {} $a
1 is not foo
2 is not foo
3 is not foo
4 is not foo
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
foo() { echo "$1 is not $2"; }
export -f foo
seq 4 > txt
a=0
cat txt | parallel foo {} $a
```